# Civilization going backwards. How to?

Tags: civilization, time

When we talk about civilization rollback, it's usually some kind of post nuclear war scenario, where everything is in ruins but the knowledge isn't lost.

After some huge catastrophe, we'll still have information in books, computers and sooner or later can restore lots of stuff.

But what must happen to our world so that we really get to medieval times? In order to lose most of the science data and technology for good but to keep human civilization. How can it happen?

P.S. Yap, I know in reality it can't happen. We have too many books. But I am interested even in some pure imaginative scenarios for this.

Comment: Question rolled back to the first version. The second version, being completely different, can be posted, and answered, as a separate question.

Comment: I suggest you look up the bronze age collapse.

Comment: There's a big difference between theory and practice.  For instance, I have a general idea of how one goes about making a microprocessor, producing steel from iron ore, or any number of things, but I really don't have the practical experience - that is, all the stuff than generally doesn't get written down - do actually do them.

Answer (score 3):

Not only would you have to erase all paper book sources and sources of data, you also have to erase the ability of people to record knowledge. Because it's not just in data bases and on paper, it's in people's heads as well.

And you would also have to keep them from progressing.

I've seen an example of this in Stargate Atlantis and Stargate. Basically, you have a power greater than the people there that NEEDS people--be it the Wraith for feeding or the G'ould for labor, incubation and hosts. Both the Wraith and the G'ould watch these civilizations and stamp out any progress. Any place that advances is a threat to their rule. Of course, it doesn't entirely work, but for the most part, most of these worlds stay agrarian, or at least pretend to be.

It doesn't have to be something so involved, but you might have an alien civilization that releases nanites that take apart anything beyond a certain tech level, on a molecular level. The nanites would have to be smart and adaptive. I can't see them working forever, even if they are self-replicating. But hey, aliens. You can handwave a lot.

Basically, that would mean that any attempt to build/write down something beyond a certain threshold of tech simply falls apart.